# How to replace last element (or any element) of every row in an ndarray with a constant?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want replace last element of every row in an ndarray with a constant. Currently I can solve this by using loops, but i'm looking for an elegant solution. preferably using `numpy` functions.

for example i have a ndarray :

```
[1 3 4 5]
[4 2 4 1]
[3 2 7 3]
[7 9 4 3]
[6 9 7 2]
```

Here is the result i want, with last element of every row is replaced with 10

```
[1 3 4 10]
[4 2 4 10]
[3 2 7 10]
[7 9 4 10]
[6 9 7 10]
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: What is the code you having problems with?

Comment: i don't have code right now. assume ndarray as x.

Comment: shape of array is (5,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use numpy indexing for columns

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,3,4,5],
     [4,2,4,1],
     [3,2,7,3],
     [7,9,4,3],
     [6,9,7,2]])
arr[:,-1]=10
arr
array([[ 1,  3,  4, 10],
       [ 4,  2,  4, 10],
       [ 3,  2,  7, 10],
       [ 7,  9,  4, 10],
       [ 6,  9,  7, 10]])
```

Comment: no problem, you should consider taking a look at numpy [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing#module-numpy.doc.indexing)